# How are rotation matrices used in structural VAR identification through sign restrictions?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics

I saw this identification method is used in several working papers but to me it is impossible to understand how it works by simply reading them.
I have searched many books and lecture notes in order to read something about it but I found either nothing clear or nothing at all.

Does anyone know what is the sense of this methodology and how it helps in the identification process?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: "several working papers"  Which?  And consider including an example from one of them so you can talk about specific aspects that you find unclear.